# editEvent reload page even if nothing change

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

When I click on an event in my calendar (made with fullcalendar3) it apparead a modal where I can change name, start and end of the event.
When I close this modal it reload the page, no matter if i change something or not.

**Is there a way to stop the page from reload if I dont make changes?**

This is my function to edit events in **JS**:

```
    eventClick: function eventClick(event) {
    $('#editNewEvent').modal('show').one('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            event.title = $('#editEname').val();
            event.start = $('#editStarts').val();
            event.end = $('#editEnds').val();
            event.descrizione = $('#editDescrizione').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'eventi/updateEvent.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data:  {start: event.start, _id: event.idAssenza, end: event.end, title: event.title, descrizione: event.descrizione},
                success: function() {
                        location.reload();
                } 
            });
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event._id);
        });
  }
```

I found online this kind of solution:

```
    success: function(data) {
               var result = data;
               location.reload();
      } 
   });
   return result;
```

But it doesnt change anything, still reload the page even if I dont modify anything

Comment: The solution would be to handle clicking on the Submit button of the modal, rather than handling the event when the modal is hidden. But why do you want to reload the page anyway? That entirely defeats the point of using AJAX. Instead, make any changes to the display that you want to make within the current page.

Comment: I reload the page because that was the solution I found, but it will be great to have a solution to just upload the event changes without reload. I'm new to this world, coming just from HS with html and basic JS, I dont know how to do stuff if i dont look on internet and i'm trying to learn like this

Comment: Well, you didn't show how you are putting the events into fullCalendar, but if you're using a refreshable event feed (e.g. a URL which returns JSON, or a function) then you can use fullCalendar's [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/refetchEvents) method to automatically update the events from the server, which should then contain your updated data which you saved there. I mean you could call that in your AJAX "success" instead of location.reload.

Comment: P.S. In future please don't post the same question more than once! We do not need repetition cluttering up the question list, or splitting the efforts of volunteers to create answers.

Comment: I did it because one question was seen from many ppl and no one answered. Instead an other question, same topic has an answer more quickly. I think SO has a weird algorithm

Comment: In that situation you should [edit] the question, which can include changing the tags and/or updating the content to make it easier for people to understand. Take the [tour] if you don't know much about how Stackoverflow works. If you post lots of duplicate questions and the moderators notice it, they will close your duplicate questions down and in a bad case you might even be banned from asking more questions (at least temporarily).

Comment: they did with an other account of mine. My question wasnt answered per days, never duplicated, but got closing, without even ask for clarification. Change it and never reposted and after a few days banned from asking more question. I was going well with that account and they started close my question.

Comment: It's not _required_ for anyone to ask for clarification, it's your responsibility to ask clearly from the beginning. People often do ask if they think the question is rescuable or interesting, but still a question can be closed without that happening. But...a question can also be re-opened if you edit it to make it clearer again. Also if you edit a question, it goes back nearer the top of the list in its chosen topics, so more people are likely to see it. Having your question closed is not a reason to post duplicates, and anyway none of these ones in your new account have been closed.

Comment: I in fact refered to an old account. None here have been closed but I post duplice with the fearing of being closed and dont get asnwered to stuff it's been days I have trouble.

Comment: How exaclty can I edit my question to be more clarify if I dont know where I wasnt clear? English is not even my first language so it more difficult for me to understand where i wasnt being clear.

Comment: Okay, the part where if I edit my question it goes in the first places i didnt know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an other question of mine I had this solution:

```
eventClick: function eventClick(event) {
    $('#editNewEvent').modal('show');
    //*salva* is the ID of my button
    $("#salva").click(function() {
            event.title = $('#editEname').val();
            event.start = $('#editStarts').val();
            event.end = $('#editEnds').val();
            event.descrizione = $('#editDescrizione').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'eventi/updateEvent.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data:  {start: event.start, _id: event.idAssenza, end: event.end, title: event.title, descrizione: event.descrizione},
                success: function() {
                        location.reload();
                } 
            });
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event._id);
        });
  }
```